# Update/Refresh config file

Tags: c#, directory, app-config, updating

I have a small programm in which i copy paste stuff from A to B on the PC. The directory paths are written in the config, and when i (in the application) change the directory in the textbox it is updating the config file. I checked it, the value is immediatlely rewritten at the appropriate key. When i close the app and reopen it, it is updatet to the previously changed directory path, but i dont want to have to close the application and reopen is. I have a combobox and i want it to update as soon as the combobox reselect event triggers. But during the runtime (altough it is already changed in the config) it will not update the directory path shown in the app.

I read through and tried everything i found online and sadly nothing helped. Not every every kind of

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

THis is my config:

```
<appSettings file="">
<clear />
<add key="SourcepathClient" value="D:\xxx" />
<add key="SourcepathWin32" value="D:\xxx" />
<add key="DestinationpathUpdatePackages" value="D:\xxx" />
<add key="DestinationpathClient" value="D:\xxx" />
<add key="5_9_0-DestinationpathClient" value="D:\xxxt" />
<add key="5_9_0-DestinationpathUpdatePackages" value="D:\xxx" />
<add key="5_9_1-DestinationpathClient" value="D:\xxx" />
<add key="5_9_1-DestinationpathUpdatePackages" value="D:xxx" />
<add key="5_9_2-DestinationpathClient" value="D:\xxx" />
<add key="5_9_2-DestinationpathUpdatePackages" value="D:\xxx" />
</appSettings>
```

and this the code:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "UpdatePackager.exe")); 
config.AppSettings.Settings[ComboBoxVersion.Text + "-DestinationpathClient"].Value = TextBoxDestinationpathClient.Text;
config.AppSettings.Settings[ComboBoxVersion.Text + "-DestinationpathUpdatePackages"].Value = TextBoxDestinationpathUpdatePackage.Text; 
config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

I hope someone can help me.
Regards

Comment: maybe try to write your own config xml file?

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no issue with code it issue related your access, it makes a difference if you run your application in IIS and run your test sample from Visual Studio. The ASP.NET process identity is the IIS account, ASPNET or NETWORK SERVICES (depending on IIS version).

Might need to grant ASPNET or NETWORK SERVICES Modify access on the folder where web.config resides.